# Ubuntu Setting Environment variables for proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, sudo, environment

Ubuntu version: 18.04

For using web proxy, I set environments about proxy in bashrc and it works!

`export http_proxy=""
export https_proxy=""
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1, localhost`

However it doesn't work in sudo command.

`sudo -E apt-get update`

`sudo bash
apt-get update`

These two works fine but `sudo apt-get update` doesn't work.
I think there is some problem related to environment setting under sudo command.

So when i try to download gnome software with Ubuntu Software, it doesn't connect to web proxy, so it fails to download.

How should I set environment for sudo command?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

killall gnome-software
```

> You can change the http/https/ftp proxy environmental variables using
>   the following commands:

```
export {http,https,ftp}_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
```

> or else

```
ALT+F2 > network > Network proxy > Method = NO proxy > apply system wide.
```

Comment: Thnaks. However there was no problem setting proxy environmental variables. The main problem was when I use 'sudo', it fails to maintain the environment I set and fails to work properly.